# file handling in c++ " I want to add a new string at the end of the file How Can I do it? please help"

Tags: c++

I want to add new string at the end of file when I register new user its overwrite the previous values.

```
write.open("usersinfo.txt");
if (write.is_open())
{
    write << username << "\t" << password << "\t" << cnpassword << "\t" << email << "\t" << number << "\n\n";

    cout << "\n\n\nPlease Wait Your Data Is Saving";
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout << ".";
        Sleep(400);
    }
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tSign Up Successfull";
    write.close();
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
write.open("usersinfo.txt", std::ios::app);
```

to open the file with the write pointer already at the end (i.e., if you want to append to the file).

EDIT: Upon double-checking the standard, the first edit turned out to be unnecessary. `std::ios::app` implies `std::ios::out` (27.9.1.4).

Answer (score 0):

you should open your file in append mode so you can add your new text after what you have writen before.
The right way is 
write.open("usersinfo.txt", std::ios::app);
instead 
write.open("usersinfo.txt"); is equal to 
write.open("usersinfo.txt", std::ios::out);